# ThreadPoolExecutor more threads=slower android

Tags: java, android

```
   BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
                ThreadPoolExecutor ex = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1, 1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES, queue);

                final HashMap<String,Response> responses = new  HashMap<String,Response>();

                ex.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);
                        Response response = getService().getProducts();
                        responses.put("1",response);


                    }
                });
....
....

...


 ex.shutdown();
 ex.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.DAYS);
 long  time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I make many requests that I want to be notified when finished.

Testing on android 2.3 gingerbead on old device with ThreadPoolExecutor with 1 thread takes 1-1.2 seconds. Using 4 threads takes lot more 4-5 seconds!.

Testing on galaxy tab 3 it takes with one thread  100 milliseconds with 4 it takes 60 ms.

Why does this happen ??

Comment: Note that instead of manually creating your thread pool you could use a pre-configured one with the `Executors.newXxxxThreadPool` methods.

Comment: i know but didnt try that to have configuration. thank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No matter how many threads you create, you only have so many physical cores in your processor.

The older device probably has one core, so with more threads it constantly has to jump between the threads to process them.

The new device has multiple cores so can spread the threads out over them and run them in parallel.

In general for intensive tasks you should never start more threads than you have cores. For tasks that only run occasionally more threads can be ok but something like a ScheduledExecutor with a thread pool behind it would still be better.

Comment: the reason I did it because when using remote server has high latency 200ms.(ping) So speaking for new device if i serialize   all requests they add up.  But if they run at threads the network latency seems to be eliminated.However using more threads leads to undesired result in older device.Is there a solution for this?Should I create threads depending on some formula ?

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();` - just start that many threads would be a decent starting point. It's a bit odd that you getting the described behaviour though as waiting for a network response would parallelize even on a single core.

Comment: I know its odd dont know why it happens